# Javascript/Jquery calculate dynamic textbox form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I got a jquery code to create dynamic textbox. Here's my jquery code:

```
    var rowNum = 0;
    function addRow(frm) {
    rowNum ++;
    var row = '<p id="rowNum'+rowNum+'">Tanggal: <input type="text" class="datepick" name="qty[]" id="date'+rowNum+'" value="'+frm.add_qty.value+'" readonly="readonly"> Harga: <input type="text" name="name[]" value="'+frm.add_name.value+'" readonly="readonly"> <input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="removeRow('+rowNum+');"></p>';
    jQuery('#itemRows').append(row);
    frm.add_qty.value = '';
    frm.add_name.value = '';
    }

    function removeRow(rnum) {
    jQuery('#rowNum'+rnum).remove();
    }
```

and here's my form code:

```
   <div class="form-group">
   <label>Price Given</label>
      <div id="itemRows">                                
      <label class="strong">Date: <input type="text" name="add_qty" class="datepick" id="date[]" /> 
      Price: <input type="text" name="add_name" /> 
        <input onclick="addRow(this.form);" type="button" value="Add" />
     </div>
    </div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Total</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="total" id="total" />
    <button type="button" name="calculate">Calculate</button>
</div>
```

My problem is, how to create my textbox 'total' can automatically or can calculate (by pressing button calculate) the total of textbox 'add_name' (price)? I hope there's an easiest/simplest way to do this calculate.

Comment: Name of the input filed which hods the value is "add_name", right?

Comment: Yes, correct! got the code from stackoverflow

Comment: Please Verify my answer. Check if the answer solves your problem

Comment: I have updated the "DEMO". Please verify. As you enter the value the total will change :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please try this code**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("input[type='text'][name='add_name']").change(function(){
            var sum = 0
            $("input[type='text'][name='add_name']").each(function(){
                sum = sum + parseInt($(this).val());
            });
            $("input[type='text'][name='total']").val(sum);
        });
    });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/9dx1cxu8/8/)

Comment: Hello, thanks for answer, i already tried that being this: http://jsfiddle.net/9dx1cxu8/5/ but it's not automatically change the total value. or this method is used for the button? Sorry, I have minim knowledge at jquery

Comment: Its always pleasure to help others :)

Answer (score 0):

try this one.

```
$('[name="calculate"]').on('click', function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $('[name="add_name"]').each(function() {
        sum += $(this).val();
    })
    $('#total').val(sum);
})
```